# Jar runs but exits immediately

Tags: java, jar

This should be a fairly simple question but i have scoured the web without an answer.

I have an application in IntelliJ, it runs/debugs fine and does everything i expect. When i build the jar however and i run it, it gives me some generic version information instead.

Here is the output:

https://gyazo.com/178cee06604e8135cf331ee86827dff4

I must be doing something clearly wrong.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: If possible post text but not pictures. It output in terminal window, so it easy to copy! And as it not too long, include it in question as code block.

Comment: What do you expect it to output?

Comment: This is an application that runs in the background,has a UI and the works. Its a big program but it seems to stop instantly for some reason. When i debug the same code, it works fine!